# API is returning code 500 all the time

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit, apiary

My task is to send data to API(apiary) using POST. I am using retrofit and when I do post API is returning code 500.

My Retrofit client method looks like this:

```
@POST("api/employees")
Call<Employee> createEmployee(@Body Employee e);
```

I am making call like this:

```
EmployeeClient client = retrofit.create(EmployeeClient.class);
    Call<Employee> call = client.createEmployee(employee);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Employee>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Employee> call, Response<Employee> response) {
            Toast.makeText(CreateEmployeeActivity.this, "code" + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Employee> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(CreateEmployeeActivity.this, "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

When I look to apiary inspector expected value for POST is something like this:

```
+ Part (name="json")
{
    "name": "John",
    "department": "IT",
    "address": "Somewhere",
    "photoUrl": "http://www.example.com/tesing/employees/65/photo"
}
+ Part (name="photo"; filename="filename.jpg")
```

If I look in POST description the photoUrl and photo is optional so in my POST I am sending Employee without the Photo file.

Comment: There is may be syntax error on your api

Comment: What does 500 mean?

Comment: Internal Server Error. If I am not wrong so that 500 have to be something on server side or some undefined behevior.